# Wake up and shut down - What is the difference between repeat and scheduled?

Tags: sleep-wake, ventura, macos, pmset

Unfortunately, Ventura doesn't support the GUI for poweron/poweroff.
I want my Mac to startup on Sunday 04:00. So I enter

```
sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron U 04:00:00
```

Then

```
sudo pmset sched -g
```

shows Sunday as expected, but also:

```
Repeating power events:
  wakepoweron at 4:00 AM Sunday

Scheduled power events:
    [0]  wake at 01/12/2023 09:42:46 by 'com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.acmd.alarm'
```

It seems to me, that `repeat` and `scheduled` are not the same and handled differently. Accordingly, entering

```
sudo pmset repeat cancel
```

deletes the expected start on Sunday, but the scheduled 9:42 event remains active. A command like

```
sudo pmset sched cancel
```

is not accepted.

What is the difference between `repeat` and `scheduled`?